# Remote GUI client for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have searched enough on the web but did not find the solution.

Is there a remote GUI client for Elastic Search server just like Oracle SQL Developer in order to see the schema & other details of the remote elastic db.

Currently I am using the elastic head plugin

[image]

It doesn't let me connect to the remote elastic cluster. It only works if the elastic server is hosted in the same machine. I also added the below entries to elastic.yml file but doesn't works. Says `no connection to the remote host`.

```
#http.cors.enable: true
#http.cors.allow-origin: "remotehosturl:9200"
```

Comment: Just to make sure: you didn't include the `#` character in front of those two lines, right?

Comment: well all the entries in elastic.yml have that, so I put

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to remove the `#` character in front your two lines, as that comments out the line and thus has no effect.

Also the [correct settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2) for CORS is named `http.cors.enabled` not `http.cors.enable`

So you should include these two lines:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "remotehosturl:9200"
```

Also you have the choice with [other plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/management.html), such as [Marvel](https://www.elastic.co/products/marvel), [Kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf) or the Sense Chrome plugin (soon available as a [Kibana-powered standalone tool](https://www.elastic.co/blog/sense-2-0-0-beta1))

Comment: tried everything but for some reason still it doesn't work. I am trying to connect the same url with sense chrome plugin. It works fine.

Comment: Can you comment out the `allow_origin` line (i.e. add the `#` character at the beginning of the line) and see if it works? If not, can you replace the value simply with `*`?

Answer (score 5):

Dejavu is a MIT-licensed modern alternative to Elasticsearch Head, I am one of the contributors to the project.

You can use it as a [remote web app](https://dejavu.appbase.io), a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dejavu/jopjeaiilkcibeohjdmejhoifenbnmlh) or as a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/appbaseio/dejavu/).

It supports:

- Excel like UI for CRUD operations - including ability to view and add mappings from GUI,
- Visual filters,
- Ability to import CSV / JSON files directly,
- Query views,
- Export data in CSV / JSON formats.

When using it in a remote mode, you will have to set the Elasticsearch config to allow CORS from the origin where dejavu's app is running.

You can read more about the project at https://github.com/appbaseio/dejavu.

Answer (score 2):

Marvel's sense is  official GUI client for elasticsearch maintained by elastic.It is now even free to use in production with ES release 2.0. Sense query user interface has intellisense hooked with it which is very usefull when writing complex queries and offer lot of other metrics about cluster health, CPU load, memory(build on top of kibana).I prefer sense over head.It is worth taking a look atleast.

You have to install this plugin on your remote server.
Installation- https://www.elastic.co/downloads/marvel

Comment: Should note that Marvel is a commercial package. Its probably good - but n/a for many.